# why i faced the Error Cannot find module protobufjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm, npm-scripts

im using the node library that called node-dota2
I've done all the requirements that node-dota2 needs from this site https://github.com/Arcana/node-dota2#installation-and-setup
1-installed it with npm
2-make file called config.js
3-changed line 5 to dota2
4-make an empty file called sentry

when i run the app with (node example.js) i faced this error
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5dxV.png)
don't know how to fix it ? pls Help

Comment: Without me having to view the whole installation, did the instruction mention doing -> `npm install protobufjs`  because that's what it says it can't find.

Comment: i used it and it cuz another error => (it cuz another error witch is => ( TypeError: ProtoBuf.newBuilder is not a function )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing a specific version of protobufjs:
`npm install protobufjs@4.1.3`

Comment: fixed the error for me, thank you. seems like with the latest version something was broken

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the protobufjs package. Install the package using `npm i protobufjs` and restart your application.

Comment: it cuz another error witch is => ( TypeError: ProtoBuf.newBuilder is not a function ) i don't know what this is ?